# JQuery game - Make player stay inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help making my player stay inside of the my div. My player is a div that can move and it is placed inside of an "arena" div that has an border! Can somone help me make so that the player can't move outside of the div!

Here is a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z61wxo9x/) of my project! 
Here is my code!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#bana").append("<div id='spelare1'></div>"); //Sätter in spelaren
    $("#bana").append("<div id='obj_poäng'></div>"); //Sätter in poäng obj

    $("#tid").text("Tid: " + tid); //Sätter tid texten
    $("#poäng").text("Poäng: " + poäng) //Sätter poäng texten

    sättSpelareHöjd(); //Kallar på sättSpelareHöjd funktionen vid start
});

var knappTryckt = true;
var tid = 60; //Tiden i spelet
var poäng = 0; //Start poäng

function sättSpelareHöjd() {
    var spelareHöjd = $("#spelare1").width();
    $("#spelare1").css("height", spelareHöjd);
} //Sätter spelarens höjd så att den hela tiden är en kub

//Spelare 1 rörelse
$(document).keydown(function(e){
if(knappTryckt) {
    if(e.keyCode == 37) {
        $("#spelare1").stop().animate({left: "-=" + 100 + "%"},5000);
        //Pil vänster
    }

    else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        $("#spelare1").stop().animate({top: "-=" + 100 + "vh"},5000);
        //Pil upp
    }

    else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        $("#spelare1").stop().animate({left: "+=" + 100 + "%"},5000);
        //Pil höger
    }

    else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        $("#spelare1").stop().animate({top: "+=" + 100 + "vh"},5000);
        //Pil ner
    }

    knappTryckt = false;
}
});
$(document).keyup(function(){
    $("#spelare1").stop();
    knappTryckt = true;
});
```

Comment: what have you tried to do to stop the element form leaving the field?

Comment: @madalinivascu - I have not directly tried anything at the moment and that is why Im asking for help, I don't know how I need to do it!

Comment: make player a js object with position parameters that rerenders HTML DOM on movement (You could limit even the html dom update - limit FPS). Give the position values min and max, that it can't go over... Easier is not make player a js object and instead just use global vars for position and again - limit these values.

Comment: I don't know the exact solution, but i can recommend you to draw box with `-` , and then check through jQuery, whether `left child`/`rightchild` and so on.

Comment: @AdamK. - Will that work if i resize the window? Our teacher wants us to make it responsive and my characters move in % values. If i asign an X value that increses when you hold down left arrow key, will it work good if i use % values?

Comment: Well if you make an interval to check the player position and playfield dimension at the same time. `setInterval(function(){},16)` -(around 60Hz check) When player is out of bounds, just return him to the max values. So when you resize the field, he should be set back to the bounds.

`var PlayerPos=$("#spelare1").position();PlayerPos.left;PlayerPos.top;
var BanaWidth=$("#bana").width();var BanaHeight=$("#bana").height();`

Comment: @AdamK. Thanks! Will try that!

Comment: @robeng updated comment - you could use position and dimensions values like this.

Comment: @robeng see my answer below

Comment: @madalinivascu. I Will have look and see what I under stand and what I can do with it! Thank you for helping!

Comment: @AdamK. I will have a look! Thanks you for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the progress property of animate to get the current postion of the item and `position()` to get the item position left & top:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#bana").append("<div id='spelare1'></div>"); //Sätter in spelaren
  $("#bana").append("<div id='obj_poäng'></div>"); //Sätter in poäng obj

  $("#tid").text("Tid: " + tid); //Sätter tid texten
  $("#poäng").text("Poäng: " + poäng) //Sätter poäng texten

  sättSpelareHöjd(); //Kallar på sättSpelareHöjd funktionen vid start
  sättPoängHöjd(); //Kallar på sättPoängHöjd funktion vid start
  poängPosition(); //Kallar på poängPosition vid start
});

var knappTryckt = true;
var tid = 60; //Tiden i spelet
var poäng = 0; //Start poäng

function sättSpelareHöjd() {
  var spelareHöjd = $("#spelare1").width();
  $("#spelare1").css("height", spelareHöjd);
} //Sätter spelarens höjd så att den hela tiden är en kub

//Spelare 1 rörelse
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (knappTryckt) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
      $("#spelare1").stop().animate({
        left: "-=" + 100 + "%"
      }, {
        duration: 5000,
        progress: function() {
          var pos = $(this).position();
          if (pos.left < 0) {
            $(this).stop();
          }
        }
      });
      //Pil vänster
    } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
      $("#spelare1").stop().animate({
        top: "-=" + 100 + "vh"
      },{
        duration: 5000,
        progress: function() {
          var pos = $(this).position();
          if (pos.top < 0) {
            $(this).stop();
          }
        }
      });
      //Pil upp
    } else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
      $("#spelare1").stop().animate({
        left: "+=" + 100 + "%"
      },{
        duration: 5000,
        progress: function() {
          var pos = $(this).position();
          if (pos.left > $('#bana').width()-$("#spelare1").width()) {
            $(this).stop();
          }
        }
      });
      //Pil höger
    } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      $("#spelare1").stop().animate({
        top: "+=" + 100 + "vh"
      },{
        duration: 5000,
        progress: function() {
          var pos = $(this).position();
          if (pos.top > $('#bana').height()-$("#spelare1").height()) {
            $(this).stop();
          }
        }
      });
      //Pil ner
    }

    knappTryckt = false;
  }
});
$(document).keyup(function() {
  $("#spelare1").stop();
  knappTryckt = true;
});
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/z61wxo9x/2/

Comment: Just a thought - not giving a finished complete solution could've been better... Figuring out how to put the stuff together by himself/herself would "give more" (since it's a homework) :P

Comment: didn't know that :)